Example of subGaussian with var(X)=1 and $||X||_{\psi_2}$ = M$.
I have an exercise that states:
Show that for any $M \geq 1$ there is a r.v. $X$ with var$(X)=1$ and $||X||_{\psi_2} = M$. Where $||\cdot||_{\psi_2}$ is define as follow: For a sub Gaussian r.v. $X$ define $||X||_{\psi_2}$ as the minimal $\sigma$ for which $X$ is $\sigma$-SubGaussian.
Can anyone help me on this with some hints?
